# Imagemagick mogrify with shadow geometry

Tags: command-line, images, imagemagick, image-manipulation, mogrify

How can I specify the size of a shadow with imagemagick?

This command works:

```
montage foo.jpg bar.jpg foobar.jpg -background lightgray -geometry 1031x1642+57+57 -shadow -monitor -tile 3x1 out.png
```

While this one gives an error:

```
montage foo.jpg bar.jpg foobar.jpg -background lightgray -geometry 1031x1642+57+57 -shadow 100x10+200+200 -monitor -tile 3x1 out.png
```

The error being:

> montage: unable to open image `100x10+200+200': No such file or
>   directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2675. montage: no decode delegate
>   for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was looking at the "mogrify" command instead :/

Answer (score 0):

You can only turn montage shadow on or off (it doesn't accept color, fuzziness & offset). Mogrify supports more shadow options, though...

(Thanks don_crissti)